# Testing several implementation of one interface

Tags: python, unit-testing

Suppose that I have an interface defined like this:

```
class MyInterface(abc.ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def my_method(self, *params):
         pass
```

And several implementations of it.

```
class Implentation1(MyInterface):
     pass

class Implentation2(MyInterface):
     pass
```

All of these classes must be tested under the same class. I was wondering it there is any way to specify that you want a test case to be run with different classes. I am using nosetests and unittest.

Comment: You could `parametrize` the tests, and feed them a list of the implementations.